# "Cannot connect to catalog" error with admin managed excel add-in

Tags: excel, office-js

When we try to load an admin managed add-in it shows this message "Cannot connect to catalog". We checked and we do have permission to access it and it loads fine in a different machine within the same network. Do you guys have any suggestion what could be the cause of not working in a particular machine using the same account and network? Or is there any way to debug this? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Turn on a feature called "optional connected experience" under Account Privacy -> Manage Settings.

[image]